# Linux command variable substitution

Tags: linux, bash, zip, sh

I would like to zip all files/dirs while excluding a few listed within the variable $excludes. However the following piece of code is not excluding those files.

```
excludes='"dir1/*" "dir2/*" "dir3/*"'
zip -r zipfile * -x $excludes
```

Comment: Can you try: `zip -r zipfile * -x dir1/* dir2/* dir3/*`

Comment: yep that works, the problem is with the variable substitution...

Comment: Try `excludes='dir1/* dir2/* dir3/*'`

Comment: user3388884 what was your solution?

Comment: excludes='dir1/* dir2/* dir3/*' works, but it also creates empty directories 1, 2, & 3

Comment: did you attempt my suggestion below to escape the *?

Comment: yea, didn't work either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
zip -r zipfile * -x dir1/* dir2/* dir3/*
```

Or even this should work:

```
excludes='dir1/* dir2/* dir3/*'
zip -r zipfile * -x "$excludes"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried escaping the asterisk with a backslash:

```
excludes='"dir1/\*"'
```

Comment: @user338884 - this worked for me:  
`dna='dir1/*\* dir2 /*\*'`  
`zip archive.zip * -x $dna`